# Deep copy of sublists

Tags: python

I have a deep list `a=[[1, 2], 3]` for which I want to copy the first entry (the sublist) of the list multiple times to get `[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], 3]`.

The following works:

```
a=[[1, 2], 3, 4]
for _ in range(2):
    a = [a[0][:]] + a
print(a) # [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], 3, 4]
a[0][0] = 5
print(a) # [[5, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], 3, 4]
```

When doing a list comprehension, I create only shallow copies:

```
a=[[1, 2], 3, 4]
a = [a[0][:]] * (3) + a[1:]
print(a)    # [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], 3, 4]
a[0][0] = 5
print(a) # [[5, 2], [5, 2], [5, 2], 3, 4]
```

Question: How can I create deep copies of the sublist in a pythonic way?

Comment: `copy.deepcopy(a)`

Comment: What do you consider as *"pythonic"* way?

Comment: By pythonic I mean not using a loop :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `*`; use another list comprehension.

```
a = [a[0][:] for _ in range(3)] + a[1:]
```